# i want to stream the rtsp video but it showing unhandled exception error how to solve it

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, video-streaming, path-provider

```
Future<void> _convert Frames To Video(
    Directory app Doc Dir,
    Flutter FFmpeg flutter FFmpeg,
  ) async {
    await flutter FFmpeg . execute(
      '-r 30 -i ${appDocDir.path}/output_%04d.jpg ${app Doc Dir. path}/output_video.mp4',
    );
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Missing Plugin Exception(No implementation found for method execute FFmpeg With Arguments on channel flutter _ffmpeg)
Method Channel invoke Method package flutter src services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
 <asynchronous suspension>
Flutter FFmpeg execute With Arguments (package : flutter _ffmpeg /flutter_ffmpeg.dart:441:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
_My Home Page State. _capture Frames (package : ffmpeg in build /main.dart:83:5)
 <asynchronous suspension>
```